# Loop for dictionary

Tags: python

I have a data structure called `Deny`:

```
{'1': {'From': '00:00:00:00:00:02', 'To': '00:00:00:00:00:01'},
 '2': {'From': '00:00:00:00:00:03', 'To': '00:00:00:00:00:04'}}
```

I need to loop through to print values associated with From and To. Here's what I have so far:

Calling the function:

self.Add(*Deny)

Called function:

```
def Add(*Deny):
    for x in Deny.values():
        log.debug("From is %s",x['From'])
        log.debug("To is %s",x['To'])
```

I get error message like: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'`. I'm expecting an output like this:

```
From is 00:00:00:00:00:02
To is 00:00:00:00:00:01
From is 00:00:00:00:00:03
To is 00:00:00:00:00:04
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this `for` loop?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation and stop trying to write C in Python. `*` is not a pointer https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: All you have to do is get rid of that `*` and your code will work as intended...

Comment: And just for kicks, here is a one-liner for you: ``log.debug('\n'.join('From is {}\nTo is {}'.format(x['From'], x['To']) for x in Deny.values()))``. I didn't test it, but I'd think it performs a bit better than your code.

Comment: If i get rid off * in my code, i get this message "Add() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" . What should i do more? @atlspin

Comment: Do you have add() as part of a class?  If so then it is getting 'self' as its first parameter, and you need to account for that in the signature

Answer (score 4):

You are using `*args` which is a `tuple` of arguments so calling .values on a tuple is obviously not going to work, it would be `**kwargs` if you want to use keyword args which returns a dict so `.values()` would work, if you want to iterate over the args just iterate over `Deny`:

```
for x in Deny:
```

If you are just passing a single argument ie your dict then forget `*` and `**` just use `def Add(Deny)` and then you can use `for x in Deny.values():`

[what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: @Explore_SDN,  the link is to a question on SO that covers the topic in great detail

Answer (score 0):

When you use *Deny in a method definition, * refers to a tuple of arguments, i.e. later if use the Add method with arguments `Add(a,b,c,d)`, variable `Deny` inside the method will be a tuple (a,b,c,d). For your problem, a simple modification as following would work.

```
def Add(Deny):
    for x in Deny.values():
        print("From is %s"%x['From'])
        print("To is %s"%x['To'])
```

Comment: When I do as you suggested i get error message "Add() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" . What should i do more? @ Kampta

Comment: try running it with `Add(Deny)` instead of `Add()`

Comment: I am using Add(Deny). Still something is wrong.  ERROR MESSAGE: self.Add(Deny)
TypeError: Add() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: if it is a class method do
```def Add(self, *Deny):```

Comment: I am now calling function as self.Add(Deny). Should i change the way i am  calling?

Comment: It worked when i did : self.Add(Deny) and def Add(self, Deny).